# Performance impact of using single join vs using multiple joins to get same results in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have two SQL queries (using Postgresql as backend ) which essentially retrieves the same results.

The two tables structures:

*values[id(int), attr(int), value(jsonb)]*

*doc_id[id(int), uuid(text)]*

They are as follows: -

```
select values.value, doc_id.uuid from values join ((select id from values where attr = 1 and value ->> 'v' LIKE '%a%') intersect (select id from values where attr = 1 and value ->> 'v' LIKE '%a%' intersect(select id from values where attr = 3 and value ->> 'v' LIKE '%b%'))) as x on values.id = x.id join doc_id on values.id = doc_id.id order by values.id, scim_user_attribute_values.attribute;
```

```
SELECT alias_value, doc_id.uuid 
FROM (SELECT values_alias.value, doc_id.uuid
FROM values JOIN values AS values_alias ON values.id = values_alias.id JOIN doc_id ON values.id = doc_id.id
WHERE values.attr = 1 AND values.value ->> 'v' LIKE '%a%' INTERSECT SELECT values_alias.value ,doc_id.uuid
FROM (SELECT  values_alias.value, doc_id.uuid
FROM values JOIN values AS values_alias ON values.id = values_alias.id JOIN doc_id ON values.id = doc_id.id
WHERE values.attr = 1 AND values.value ->> 'v' LIKE '%a%' INTERSECT SELECT values_alias.value, doc_id.uuid
FROM values JOIN values AS values_alias ON values.id = values_alias.id JOIN doc_id ON values.id = doc_id.id
WHERE values.attr = 3 AND values.value ->> 'v' LIKE "%b%" AS anon_2) AS anon_1
```

I am not sure the second query makes sense to you, but its actually the translated query from sqlalchemy python library(I have trimmed it for readability).

Those two queries might not be syntactically correct, they are given just to give an idea of what I meant.
Please, do not bother about the correctness of each query.
So I use sqlalchemy ORM library to construct my queries.

Having a look at these queries, which one do you think is more efficient and why?

Comment: Look at the execution plan of both queries first.

Comment: @PieterB, I did check the plan for both,  first query seems to be faster with execution time of 400ms, where as the second one takes 3 sec.

Comment: You also need to bear in mind that DB engines have query optimisers so the query you write is not necessarily what is being executed. Given that the query plans show different execution times it looks like the DB is executing different queries but it would be possible for you to write 2 very different queries that give the same result and for your DB to optimise them both to the same executable query

Comment: @MohanKumarUmashankar . . . Well, based on your run-time statistics, I vote that the first one is faster.  Really, the way to know is to look at the execution plans and to test.

Comment: @MohanKumarUmashankar forget about the running time a bit, but try to really understand the execution plan. It shows for instance if your intermediate result sets are large or not. And a lot of other things.